# Trying to web scrape Product Count however its returning a Null value

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to web scrape the Product count from this page
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-converters/922?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvkOIBWZCAZQwjaZDBUqIoA

[Webpage snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mixpU.png)

My current code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
url= 'https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-converters/922?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvkOIBWZCAZQwjaZDBUqIoA'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(10)
content = soup.find('span', attrs={'data-testid': 'static-product-count'})
print(content.text)
```

The html part is

```
<span data-testid="static-product-count" class="jss68">248,154 </span>
```

My code is returning a null output however, the same code would work fine a few weeks back when the html part was (but im wondering how that makes a difference? can someone help explain?) thanks!

```
<span class="jss82" data-testid="product-count">1604</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text ***248,154*** using *Selenium* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using the text *Results*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-converters/922?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvkOIBWZCAZQwjaZDBUqIoA'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='button-desktop' and @track-data='ref_page_event=Consent or View Privacy']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Results')]//span"))).text)
  ```
- Using the *`data-testid`* attribute:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-converters/922?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvkOIBWZCAZQwjaZDBUqIoA'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='button-desktop' and @track-data='ref_page_event=Consent or View Privacy']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-testid='static-product-count']"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  248,154
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why it isnt working using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Well, honestly I'm not the BeautifulSoup person :) but if you wish I can join you in your R&D